# Javascript: Break out of a loop inside of the success function of an ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, httprequest

I need to send an $.ajax request and check the response HTML to see if it contains certain text. If it does infact, i want to execute a separate function and break the current loop so it doesn't keep making requests for the other items.

I know i cannot break the loop inside the success function because it's in a scope of its own. Any solutions would be great.

```
    for(var i in list) {

      var item = list[i];

      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: baseURL + '/ChangeItems/CheckAvailability',
            data: { 'newitem': item, 'purchaseItem': false },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) { alert(textStatus); },
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data) { if(checkItem(data)) { buyItem(); break; } }
        });
   }
```

Comment: Your loop would have already finished by the time your first success function gets fired I imagine. (in most cases)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that my ajax function is actually using another queuing function, i just didn't want to clutter up the example code.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't test this code but I think it's an idea and it should work.

```
var list = [...], i = 0;
function myAjaxRequest(i)
{ 
    var item = list[i];

    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data)
        {
            if( checkItem(data) )
            {
                buyItem();
            }
            else if( typeof list[i+1] != "undefined" )
            {
                 myAjaxRequest(i+1);
            }
        }
        //, error: function(){ if( typeof list[i+1] != "undefined" ) myAjaxRequest(); }
    });
}

myAjaxRequest(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it synchronous and do the processing outside of the $.ajax:

```
for(var i in list) {
  var item = list[i];
  var result;

  $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: baseURL + '/ChangeItems/CheckAvailability',
        data: { 'newitem': item, 'purchaseItem': false },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) { alert(textStatus); },
        dataType: 'text',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) { result = data; }
   });

   if(checkItem(result)) { buyItem(); break; }
}
```

Comment: @mifeng The `async: false` makes it synchronous, so the if is executed after the $.ajax returns.

Comment: @G-Nugget oh yah. I missed that line. :)

Answer (score 0):

Test this, I had this problem and I solved right now :

```
$break=0;
 for(var i in list) {
     if ($break) { break; }
      var item = list[i];
      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: baseURL + '/ChangeItems/CheckAvailability',
            data: { 'newitem': item, 'purchaseItem': false },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) { alert(textStatus); },
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data) { if(checkItem(data)) { buyItem(); $break = 1; } }
        });
   }
```

Is not possible break the loop inside ajax response.

Answer (score -1):

You could store each xhr object from the async request in an array and cancel all the following requests upon one of them finishing successfully.

```
var xhrList = [];
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: baseURL + '/ChangeItems/CheckAvailability',
    data: { 'newitem': item, 'purchaseItem': false },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) { alert(textStatus); },
    dataType: 'text',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) { 
        for(var i = 0; i < xhrList.length; i++){
            xhrList[i].abort();
        } 
    }
});
xhrList.push(xhr);
```

Comment: This is just a rough example - you will have to check the state of the xhr object before aborting it to make sure it's in the right state